# C++/CLI mix mode dll's in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, com, asp.net-core, mixed-mode

Has Microsoft released the details on implementing mix-mode .dlls (native/.net) inside of vNext?

What about COM bindings? I know it's an old technology, but it is still widely used. Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we will see any com bindings since that is windows specific but it should be possible to use native dlls though work is still in progress as discussed in this question [Interop with unmanaged code in ASP.net vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967220/interop-with-unmanaged-code-in-asp-net-vnext)